# Why i can not add data into new added column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am amateur C# developer.Now i'm working on destkop application and work with MS2015 and SQL Management Studio.I have added new column into my database and write what is needed for it in .cs code,but can not add my data into column.It always shows NULL even if it is not empty.Here is my code about saving data:

```
       private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
            if (txtAmount.Text=="" ||txtBarcode.Text == "" || txtName.Text == "" || txtEntrance.Text == "" || txtExit.Text == "" || txtQuantity.Text == "" || txtStatus.Text == "") 
            {
                SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Nicat\Downloads\CompError.wav");
                sp.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill all gaps!");
            }
            else
            {
                model.Amount = txtAmount.Text.Trim();
                model.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
                model.Entrance_Time = txtEntrance.Text.Trim();
                model.Exit_Time = txtExit.Text.Trim();
                model.Status = txtStatus.Text.Trim();
                model.Quantity = txtQuantity.Text.Trim();
                model.Barcode_No = txtBarcode.Text.Trim();


                using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
                {
                    if (model.ID == 0)

                        db.Tables.Add(model);

                    else
                        db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                Reset();
                PopulateDataGridView();
                SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Nicat\Downloads\Button.wav");
                sp.Play();


                    MessageBox.Show("Inventory submitted succesfully!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Amount is my new column

Comment: I think before updating the state of model, you need to attach it. Like - db.Tables.Attach(model); and then you modify the state and save.

Comment: Sir,i have done it but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you add an exception handler, it will tell you what's wrong.

Wrap your code in a try/catch block.

```
try
{
    // your code goes here
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Writeln(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Terry Carmen,sir i used try/catch block but it showed no problem